# Replace string from nested list with value from Dictionary in Python

Tags: python, string, list, dictionary, integer

i have a list of lists

```
month_list = [['January', 'february', 'march'], ['april', 'may', 'june']]
```

and this dictionary with key = string, value = int

```
month_ids = {     'January': 1,
                  'february': 2,
                  'march': 3,
                  'april': 4,
                  'may': 5,
                  'june': 6
                  }
```

Can i replace the strings from my list of lists with the integers from the Dictionary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to maintain the nested structure of the initial list, the you can write *nested list comprehension* expression as:

```
>>> id_list = [[month_ids[month] for month in month_set ] for month_set in month_list]
>>> id_list
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

However, if you need the *flatten list*, then you can utilise `itertools.chain()` with *list comprehension* as:

```
>>> from itertools import chain

>>> id_list = [month_ids[month] for month in chain(*month_list)]
>>> id_list
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Here `chain(*month_list)` will flatten your list of months. Then I am iterating one the list of months, and creating another list containing *id* of *month* using `month_ids[month]` inside the *list comprehension* expression.

Comment: Thanks for the information.
Sorry i am new to python and i updated my list to a correct list of lists.

Comment: can you confirm whether your nested list being `['January, february, march']` is expected or it is suppose to be `['January', 'february, 'march']` ?

Comment: i think the second option ['January', 'february, 'march'] would be even more interesting for my case.

Comment: @new_guy_around updated the answer as per your recent edit. However if there's any thing which you missed in the question and want to edit which may change the context of question, then please create it as separate question. Because your edit in question with change in requirement makes the existing answers invalid.

Comment: ok, thanks for the information. Sorry for all the confusion

Comment: @new_guy_around if this answer helped you, you can [upvote it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) by clicking up arrow on the left. It will help me with 10 reputation gain.

Answer (score 0):

this line

```
for i in range(len(month_list)):
    month_list[i] = months_ids[month_list[i]]
```

or

```
month_list = [months_ids[x] for x in month_list]
```

or

```
month_list = list(map(lambda x: months_ids[x], month_list))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map` and `lambda`

```
map(lambda month: month_ids.get(month), month_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding this line will work hopefully.

```
month_list = list(month_ids.values())
```